# Create a DW incl. starschema

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have 2 .BAK files and I want from that to create a small DW that I build in the new database including a star schema.

I have tried to restore the 2 bak files inside MSSM, and then it created two database.

Im confused if I have done it right or what next steps is it?

Comment: Restoring a backup will create a duplicate of the database in that backup. You will need to create your datawarehouse separately, design the schema, and then populate it from your restored databases. At least that is my guess - you did not provide much information beyond "i want ..."

Comment: @Johan; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

No, It's just two versions of a single database.

For the DW Star Schema, you should have one fact table in the centre of the star and a number of associated dimension tables.

Read More :

[Star and SnowFlake Schema in Data Warehousing](https://www.guru99.com/star-snowflake-data-warehousing.html)

[Create a Star Schema Data Model in SQL Server using the Microsoft Toolset](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5690/create-a-star-schema-data-model-in-sql-server-using-the-microsoft-toolset/)